# Couldn't figure it out how to call a function of a WSDL service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Lately I got a project and given a WSDL API without a documentation. I have been trying to figure how to pass a parameter to WSDL service located here : http://www.lme4me.com/webapp/pickupRequest2/services/PickupRequestMethodsV2/wsdl/PickupRequestMethods.wsdl

```
$this->client = new SoapClient('http://www.lme4me.com/webapp/pickupRequest2/services/PickupRequestMethodsV2/wsdl/PickupRequestMethods.wsdl',
        [
            'trace' => 1,
            'use' => SOAP_LITERAL
        ]
    );

 $data = [
            'PickupHeader' => [
                'shipperPhone' => '0507878328',
                'customerNum' => '1231231231',
                'shipCompany' => 'Optimum7',
                'shipAddress' => '141 Grand Avenue',
                'shipCity' => 'Miami',
                'shipState' => 'FL',
                'shipZip' => '33133',
                'pickDate' => '20/07/2016',
                'pickTime' => '13:00',
                'dockCloseTime' => '13:00',
                'paymentTerms' => 'P',
                'specialInstructions' => 'Test API Usage! Test Pickup',
                'shipmentDetails' => [
                    'unitType' => 'PKG',
                    'units' => '3',
                    'weight' => '44',
                    'consigneeName' => $order->ShipCompanyName,
                    'destCity' => $order->ShipCity,
                    'destState' => $order->ShipState,
                ]
            ],
        ];
        $soapCall = $this->client->RequestPickup_v2($data);
```

This call always return internal server error. How can I understand what parameter should I send by looking at the wsdl link ?

Comment: Try a Tool like SoapUI there you can generate request xmls for each method. Maybe that helps you to setup the request in PHP right.

Comment: Try to perform request with Postman https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: And `internal server error` is not a request format error , can be everything inside the API, but "can" also mean format error, A good API would show better error response